# cannot import datashader in python due to PIL/Pillow

Tags: python, datashader

when importing datashader to python 2, I got an error

```
  from . import _imaging as core
 57     if PILLOW_VERSION != getattr(core, 'PILLOW_VERSION', None):
---> 58         raise ImportError("The _imaging extension was built for     another "
 59                           "version of Pillow or PIL")
 60
```

ImportError: The _imaging extension was built for another version of Pillow or PIL

I then attempted to fix PIL by pip install PIL --allow-external PIL --allow-unverified PIL and got error

```
DEPRECATION: --allow-external has been deprecated and will be removed         in the future. Due to changes in the repository protocol, it no longer has         any effect.
DEPRECATION: --allow-unverified has been deprecated and will be removed in the future. Due to changes in the repository protocol, it no longer has any effect.
Collecting PIL
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PIL (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for PIL
```

Any suggestions? I'm running python 2 on mac with conda/pip installed. Thanks very much.

Comment: can you check what version it was built for?

Comment: also most platforms use the pillow library, its a better maintained fork, but retains backwards compatibility, try pip install pillow?

Comment: I'd recommend using conda by itself, not trying to mix it with pip.  The environment.yml shipped in examples/ should be sufficient, and will ensure that pillow is installed.

Comment: thanks both the installation works now. 
now i just need to find some datasets to use with data shader as most example notebooks didn't provide a link